# spring mvc RESTfull url

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, restful-url

I´m new in spring-mvc. So, i´m trying to use RESTFull urls ( i think that's the correct name)
For example, i want use a url like this: http://localhost:8080/sommer/Users/edit/1
it means i want to edit the user with id 1
But with my configuration it´s not getting to the any controller. I'm just able to use urls ending with .html.

This is my configuration and code

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter
    </filter-class>
  </filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.js.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <!-- 
  Spring Security
  -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml
            /WEB-INF/security-applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/sprekelia-startup.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- 
    Spring Security
    -->

    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>


</web-app>
```

spring-servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


   <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.sommer.controller" />
        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sommer.service" />


    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="es"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sommer"/>
      <property name="username"  value="**"/>
      <property name="password" value="**"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
    p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaAdapter">
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
                <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
        </property>                             
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="sommerPersistenceUnit"></property>
    </bean>

     <bean id="jpaAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
    p:database="MYSQL"
    p:showSql="true"
    p:generateDdl="true"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>



</beans>
```

html

```
---
 <div class="button-group right">
                    <a href="<c:url value="/Users/edit/${user.id}"/>" class="button primary icon edit"><spring:message code="users.edit"/></a>
                    <a href="<c:url value="/Users/remove/${user.id}"/>" class="button danger icon remove"><spring:message code="users.remove"/></a>
                </div>
---
```

controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("Users")
public class SystemUserController {

    }
    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public ModelAndView index(){
        List<SystemUser> list = userRepository.findAll();

    return new ModelAndView("users/index","users",list);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/edit/{userId}")
    public ModelAndView edit(@PathVariable long userId){
        List<SystemUser> list = userRepository.findAll();

    return new ModelAndView("users/index","users",list);
    }
}
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are registering the DispatcherServlet to HTML files only when you have:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If you want no extension whatsoever, you'll have to use something along these lines:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

(Of course, keep in mind, this will literally match **everything**)

Comment: ok, but i change to that configuration, but now i getting http error HTTP 404. any idea?

Comment: First off: is it hitting your controllers now? Secondly: make sure your view-resolver is correctly configured to handle the ModelAndView your controllers are returning.

Comment: It´s getting to the controllers but it seems that what it`s not working is this line return new ModelAndView("/users/index","users",list); << i think spring mvc did not found the view (located in /WEB-INF/view/users/index.jsp. can be? and with all controllers happens the same thing

Comment: So then your view-resolver needs to be reconfigured to match your file structure. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-viewresolver

Comment: sorry, but i have this conf. and i can not find the error <bean id="viewResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass"
   value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </bean>

Comment: Can you edit your post to at least show the return line for your two controllers?

Comment: done. i`ve edited the post. it's like not finding the view return new ModelAndView("users/index","users",list);

Comment: According to your config and the return values from your controllers, you'll need to have a /WEB-INF/view/users/index.jsp file in order for your view-resolver to resolve to the correct location. Additionally, I believe you must return the view name as `users/index.jsp` instead.